# E commerce android app

Tags: android, web, content-management-system, e-commerce, android-contentprovider

My client has a requirement of making native android and ios app for the e-commerce store based in opencart cms. 
My question is, how can I dynamically load the main screen content in the app like banners, sliders etc which are subject to change every day.

I am new in the app development. Please suggest any ready to use CMS for delivering dynamic content to the app. Otherwise, please guide me on how should I approach with building this app.

P.s. I am an experienced web developer with basic android app building knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that experienced with android but here are some wild ideas, maybe it will be useful.

1. You can build a REST API which would return JSON, for example:

```js
[  
   {  
      "sliderIMG":"http://yourwebsite.com/image.png",
      "sliderTITLE":"Your title!"
   },
   {  
      "bannerIMG":"http://yourwebsite.com/image.png",
      "bannerTITLE":"Your title!"
   }
]
```

And then your mobile app upon launch would connect by using some REST API Library (Volley or Retrofit) and scrape data as well as display it.

2. You could make a mobile version for website and just iframe it in the app by using webClient. (However if you already are capable of this, using an app to open a website kinda defeats the purpose of having mobile app in the first place)